# New module ACL configuration in Magento 1

Tags: php, magento

I just installed a new module to my Magento website. I create a new user role group and give the permission to use this module. After I check the permission and save it, it doesn't work, and more than this, the permission is still unchecked.

I searched on the web and the problem might be in the config.xml.

There is that part of the code from config.xml:

```
     <menu>
        <customer>                
            <children>                
                <customerproducts  module="customer">
                    <title>Customer Products Settings</title>
                    <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/customerspecificproduct</action>
                </customerproducts>
            </children>
        </customer>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <Mconnect_Csproduct>
                        <title>csproduct Module</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </Mconnect_Csproduct>
                     <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <customerspecificproduct translate="title" module="csproduct">
                                        <title>Mconnect Customer Specific Product</title>
                                    </customerspecificproduct>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem in this code?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

replace this code

```
<customerspecificproduct translate="title" module="csproduct">
        <title>Mconnect Customer Specific Product</title>
</customerspecificproduct>
```

with

```
<customerproducts translate="title" module="csproduct">
         <title>Mconnect Customer Specific Product</title>
</customerproducts>
```

Comment: There is a good practice to have adminhtml.xml file with ACL configuration, then posting everything inside config.xml.